# managing special Character while processing for Paypal

Tags: special-characters, paypal, payflowpro

Recently, I found out that whenever I am sending any special character such as "ß" or a "Ö" e.g; ÄßÖÜöüß as address, paypal is not able to process it.

Then I tried URL Encoding them & sending it to paypal, but the issue is, in Paypal Manager the address values shows as encoded one, also in cases such as like these, where I send special character for every field, such as first name, last name, address, the page shows me some weird error.

I have no idea about how to send it to paypal other than urlencoding it, So please if any one have any insight into it, that would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

Paypal only accepts UTF8 strings. You need to UTF8 encode your string if it's not already.